# RADIUS with a local wired “access point”

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, wireless-access-point, freeradius

I have an unusual requirement for configuration of my network access schema.

I have Ubuntu 16.04.3 on board and I installed package **freeradius**. Also, security configuration has been completed according to [the article](https://www.packet6.com/install-freeradius-ubuntu-server/) and everything works as well. My problem is bound to unavailability to have a traditional access point like WiFi, but I have an Ethernet adapter at my PC. My strong desire is to configure the adapter as an "access point" and communicate with RADIUS as with local server. I googled and didn't find any notions about that.

Does anybody have an idea how to implement this stuff or even a reference (if I missed something)?

Comment: And what is your requirement, exactly? What would you achieve by setting up this "access point"?

Comment: I will get a network with availability to manage net-access (via 802.1X) for one or more devices (in a switch case). But the switch is optional  device, one supplicant is the main use case.

Comment: Basically, experimenting with 802.1X on Linux without a physical 802.1X-capable switch?

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Client:** On Linux, `wpa_supplicant` also works as an Ethernet 802.1X supplicant, as long as you select the apropriate driver. (After all, 802.1X is a predecesor to WPA-Enterprise.)

**Switch:** Likewise, the AP daemon `hostapd` can act as an authenticator for Ethernet using the "wired" driver (to emulate a 802.1X-capable switch), although it has no built-in ability to actually allow/deny traffic. It will process the EAPOL handshake just fine though.

Managed switches with 802.1X (aka dot1x) capability are not expensive. For setting up a home lab, you can find various TP-Link models in the $100 range.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will try for tomorrow and report you.

Comment: The plan is absolutely correct. I just would to extend the answer:
1. [The sample of wired config](https://github.com/jenssegers/RTL8188-hostapd/blob/master/hostapd/wired.conf);
2. configuration of **wpa_supplicant** completed via the command `wpa_supplicant -Dwired -ieth0 -c/path/to/config`.